# Is it ok for my wife to put utilities and/or cable in my name without me knowing or agreeing?

Tags: united-states

My wife put an electric bill and a cable TV bill in my name without me knowing and now I have a $700 electric bill and a $400 cable TV bill from a house I never lived in. We have been separated since 2014 and this was done during that time. Is there anything I can do to get these bills off?

Answer (score 3):

Apparently, this is an [identity fraud](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_theft). Bear in mind that, don't accuse anyone if you are not sure, whether it is a relation feud or whatever. Bear in mind that, this is a serious crime under 1st world country jurisdiction. A utility company cannot put anyone under a contract without any consent, one must provide the identity and consent documents.

In such case, only a person that stealing or forged OP identity (e.g. putting the social security ID, credit card no ) can make it happens. An act of revenge doesn't give either side the rights to conduct identity theft.

I suggest OP change all the online password and call up the ex to verify it (in a calm way like, "I see a strange bill and the utility company want me to report it as identity theft, just want to ask whether you know about it." ) . If the ex didn't do it, report the identity theft. Otherwise, you have the choice to talk up (possible to the parents as well) to settle it or burn the bridge.

Answer (score -1):

You're married.  That's why she can do it.

In my state, at least, if either of you has **filed** for divorce, then you can show those documents to the electric and cable companies showing how she fraudulently opened the accounts.  Then point them towards her.

However, they might not care.

1. Since they're in your name -- close the accounts.
2. Sue her for the money.
3. Check the credit bureaus to see if those bills are on your report, and -- if so -- send them copies of the divorce filings showing that you have no responsibility for her actions.

Of course... if you **haven't** filed for divorce, you're probably stuck.  Take this as a lesson learned in what happens when you procrastinate.

Also, talk to a lawyer.

Comment: Can she really do that? I only have experience in germany or poland and here she can NOT do it. As husband you are liable for common debt, but she can not enter both parties or the other parties name into a contract without signature, that is document fraud.

Comment: @TomTom if she forged a signature, it's fraud, but if she called them up, no one would blink an eye if she said, "put it in my husband's name".

Comment: Just because the utility agreed to put the bill in his name doesn't mean he consented to it, though. "Talk to a lawyer" is definitely the best advice.

Comment: Eactly. If you put a bill in someone else name it is fraud, period. Even if it is your husband. They have to ask for consent, not imply him being the sole owner. This is generally handled lax, but it also generally explodes legally in case of disagreement.

Comment: Being married does not give one spouse the authority to enter the other spouse into a binding contract without their consent.  You do no become one personally legally, you are still individuals.

Comment: @Andy and yet the courts will side with debt collectors when they come after you for your wife's debts.  OP really screwed the pooch by not filing for divorce.

Comment: @RonJohn And yet, no they won't.  Please cite the law that allows spouses to enter each other into contracts without consent.  You're flat out wrong on this.

Comment: @Andy I'm just going on experience.  Either OP's wife's boyfriend said he was OP, or OP's wife asked the businesses to put them in her husband's name and they did.

Comment: @RonJohn If the wife had someone else claim to be the husband, that's fraud.  And without an actual signature, its still fraud.  Legally, I suspect the OP would not be found liable and the wife can be charged with a crime.  But having the OPs name on a utility for a residence he never lived cannot be done legally without the OPs explicit acceptance.

Comment: @Andy note that "the wife had someone else claim to be the husband" isn't part of the question, so I didn't address that.

Comment: @RonJohn "and yet the courts will side with debt collectors when they come after you for your wife's debts" That depends on jurisdiction.

Comment: It doesn't matter whether the op mentioned it, because there is no way legally speaking in which your answer is correct.